# How to preview LaTeX equation or document in TexMaker?

Tags: compiling, texmaker

My code:

```
 \begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    2*x+y
    \end{equation}
 \end{document}
```

I found that F2 can compile as LaTeX. Compile result:

```
 Process started

 Process exited with error(s)
```

How to fixed and preview it?

Comment: What are the errors you get?

Comment: If I compile by press F2,it doesn't show any error message.Or what the compile way I should take?

Comment: I revised the original post by F1 compiling messages.If I press F1,it shows: LaTeX Error: The font size command \normalsize is not defined:
there is probably something wrong with the class file.

Comment: Please, turn the example code into the actual code you're using.

Comment: At that time,I just post all the code I know,but now I know how to get working~Thank you all~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

F2 in TeXmaker is a shortcut. What it runs is seen in the 'Tools' menu.

By default it runs 'LaTeX' but for this to compile correctly you would need your equation to be part of a complete, albeit minimal, .tex file. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \dot P = K'P+PK'^T + Cov(Kv-Gw)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

compiles without errors and should produce a .dvi file.

You may, as usual, wish to add additional packages (e.g. `amsmath`) or more code to view the snippet as intended.

Comment: What is amsmath for? How to use it?Should I apt-get install something?

Comment: To quote from the amsmath package documentation: "The amsmath package is a LaTeX package that provides miscellaneous enhancements for improving the information structure and printed output of documents
that contain mathematical formulas."

Comment: @sam: normally seen, amsmath should work out of the box.  some other packages will need installation of texlive-... packages on your linux-box

Answer (score 1):

In LaTeX, the `equation` environment typesets its entire contents (everything between `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}`) in math mode. Therefore, issuing `$...$` is not needed within the environment and causes the error. Therefore, remove the "inner" `$`'s and it should compile fine.

Comment: I removed it as the post I revised,and press F2. That problem is still the same.How to preview the result?